# Array_diff, how do i compare string and values of two different array

Tags: php, echo

I want to get the array_diff of these two array and echo by key

```
$s1=1;
$s2=7;
$s3=8;
$r=array("$s1","$s2","$s3");
$rr=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
$rrr=array_diff($r,$rr);
echo $rrr[0];
```

I was hoping to get a result like 2 but i got an error. Someone help out here.

Comment: What is the error? Always include the error message.

Comment: The array $rrr is empty when you try to print its contents which would cause the error Undefined offset: 0 if I am looking at it correctly

Comment: Yes. you are right. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for `array_diff` says that it

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Your `array1` is `$r`, and your `other array` is `$rr`.

`$r` is essentially equivalent to

```
$r = array("1","7","8");
```

We can clearly see that there are no values in `$r` that are **not** present in `$rr`. (`"1"`, `"7"`, `"8"` are all in `$rr`.)

Thus, you will receive a `E_NOTICE` when you try to access `$rrr[0]`, because `$rrr` is empty.

Perhaps you meant to [reverse the order of the two arguments](https://ideone.com/8Ww7TJ).

```
$rrr = array_diff($rr, $r);
```

---

As [Loop Me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5285928/loop-me) pointed out, `array_diff` [does not reorder your indices](https://ideone.com/6zAcSL).

What this means is that your array is now like this.

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
```

You can reorder them with [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$rrr = array_values($rrr);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/yO1biu)

Comment: You have to be careful when you print the contents after doing this. The array looks like Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )